# Error writing my.cnf: Permission denied

Tags: mysql, ssh, my.cnf

I'm attempting to edit my my.cnf file to allow remote access to mysql (by changing the bind-address). However, I'm getting a "Error writing my.cnf: Permission denied" error when I try to save (using pico through SSH).

Running `$ lsattr my.cnf` returns `---------------- my.cnf`

What do I need to do to be able to edit this file?

Thanks!

Comment: perhaps `sudo` needs to be used for those commands.

Comment: Who is the owner of `my.cnf`? Root? Then you need to become root also (`su` or `sudo`). Also you need to change the permissions so that mysql user will be able to read it (as root, you can write also to files with these permissions).

Comment: You need super privilege to save the file.

Answer (score 7):

You need to set the file **permission** as ***readable*** and ***writable***.

```
sudo chmod 644 my.cnf

sudo nano my.cnf
```

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo chmod 644 my.cnf

sudo pico my.cnf
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to edit it as root. 
Or look for at the file owner and file right with an ls -a.